# WPF Nested binding headache: access outer ListView with nested ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've got this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyFirstCollection} >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.MyOtherCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" >
                            <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding}">

                                            <!-- the error is in here somewhere -->
                                            <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OrderExclusionConverter}">
                                                    <Binding Path="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />
                                                    <Binding Path="MemberCount.MemberCountID" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </CheckBox.IsChecked>

                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>                         </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If I'm down inside "the error is in here somewhere", how do I get a binding to access the current item in MyFirstCollection?

I tried this:

```
Path="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
```

Which I thought would work, but it gives me `binding can only be set on a dependencyproperty of a dependencyobject` errors.

EDIT: posted full binding

Comment: Can you post the binding part of the XAML?  I don't think that error is related to what you think it is.

Comment: Surely you want AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem} ?

Comment: @McGarnagle Edited to include, thanks.

Comment: Look at the 1st binding in your multi-binding: `<Binding Path="{Binding DataContext,...` you try to set a binding on a binding... that's not going to work... Use it like `<Binding Path="..." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource ...}"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
<Binding Path="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />
```

is wrong. You can't set a `{Binding}` on the `Path` property of another `Binding`. What you need is this:

```
<Binding Path="DataContext" 
         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView, AncestorLevel=2}"/>
```

The problem is you seem to be confused between the **Attribute Syntax** and the **Property Element Syntax**. You may want to read more about these concepts on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059(v=vs.110).aspx).